# How can I see which meeting participant admitted a guest from the lobby into the meeting?

Tags: ipad, ms-teams

I use MS Teams on my iPad. How can I see which meeting participant admitted a guest from the lobby into the meeting?

---

> Is this an issue only on the iPad or on any device?

I have the same issue on Microsoft Teams web (https://teams.microsoft.com). I don't have MS Teams on my Android or Windows devices.

> What does the documentation of the vendor say about this?

I didn't find any relevant documentation page from the vendor (Microsoft).

> Is there a product-specific support site where this topic may have been discussed already?

Yes e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftTeams but I didn't find any relevant question at the time I posted the question.

Comment: [How can I show my research when posting a question on how to view which meeting participant admitted a guest from the lobby into an MS Teams meeting?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4270/20338)

Comment: If the function isn't available on any device (and I can confirm that it is not available on Windows either), the way forward is probably a feature request for Microsoft.

Comment: @nohillside well that's the issue; I don't know if If the function isn't available on iOS or https://teams.microsoft.com, that's why I posted the question :) some functions can be hard to find.

Comment: That's why you should do some research first before posting. You didn't find anything on the sites you looked at, and you get an answer here saying the same (but without reference to anything because it's not possible to prove nonexistence). How does it help if one random dude on the Internet basically says "I didn't find anything either"?

Comment: @nohillside 1) Sometimes I don't get an answer here saying the same (eg, someone pointed me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/audit-log-activities#microsoft-teams-activities) 2) nonexistence can be proven sometimes e.g. non-closed feature request on some official issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Teams on the iPad.